# Irish stamp but living in UK residence card application

Tags: united-kingdom, passport, residence-cards, eu-spouses

I came in on a tourist visa from the states via Ireland to the UK. Due to being blind I was not aware that they gave me a stamp in my passport in Ireland but not when I flew on the same day into the UK.

Now I am wanting to apply for a residence card here inside the UK as I am married to a German National who lives and works here but not sure if this will become a problem with the home office having only an Irish stamp in my passport?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you a US citizen?

Answer (score 2):

In response to your question, this is quite a common issue, whereby you have not been stamped in the UK. However coming to apply for your EU Residence Card will not be an issue.

You should provide a cover letter as well as airline ticket confirming your entry to the UK. The Home Office will not penalise you for this and in line with the EEA Reg 2006, which governs free movement rights, you do not need to have a valid permit to enter the UK, if you are a family member of an EEA national.